# python define a group of classes

Tags: python

Like:

```
class base:
    pass
classes = ["class1", "class2", "class3", "class4"]
for classname in classes:
    class classname(base):
        pass
```

I search for dynamic class define, and it's too complicate.

I need an easy solution.

Comment: Everybody needs easy solutions. What is your question?

Comment: There's probably a better way to do whatever you're trying to do...

Comment: Once you create these dynamically named classes, how do you plan to use them? And how do you plan to customize what they do?

Comment: :D `exec('class %s(object): pass' % 'Cat')`

Comment: @Hyperboreus: My question is just to implement the above code.

Comment: @neoascetic: don't understand `%` , what's this in python?

Comment: @AylwynLake It is string formatting.

Comment: @HughBothwell: I use this dynamically named classes to create sqlalchemy object, then insert record to database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `type` to define dynamic classes:

```
class base: pass
classNames = ["class1", "class2", "class3", "class4"]
classes = [type(name, (base,), {}) for name in classNames]
```

Although I agree with arshajii: "There's probably a better way to do whatever you're trying to do.."

Comment: I got error when call type funciont `a new-style class can't have only classic bases`

Comment: seems should be `type(name, (object, base,), {})` ?

Comment: @AylwynLake Probably if you are on py2.

Comment: @martineau Nice that you edit my answer by adding completely new code, without even mentioning that now half of the answer isn't mine. The "edit" functionality is for fixing typos, etc, not for changing or expanding the answer. What you did should have been a comment, now it is just (maybe well-intentioned) vandalism.